# Elasticsearch - filter and get matched results per hit

Tags: elasticsearch

In elasticsearch, I would like to filter a query based on an aggregation, and filter my results where the aggregated value is less than X. Similar to how an having-query in sql.

I have some testdata in elasticsearch, that looks like this.

```
[
    { 
        "user_id" : 1,
        "brand"   : "Renault"
    },
    { 
        "user_id" : 2,
        "brand"   : "Renault"
    },
    { 
        "user_id" : 1,
        "brand"   : "Renault"
    },
    { 
        "user_id" : 2,
        "brand"   : "Ford"
    }
]
```

user_id is the key I would like to use for aggregation.
Using mysql, it would be something like

```
SELECT count(*) as matching, user_id from some_table where brand = 'Renault' HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2 GROUP BY user_id
```

Is this possible using elasticsearch?

Comment: Your SQL query is wrong. Did you mean `SELECT count(*) as matching, user_id from some_table where brand = 'Mercedes' HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2 GROUP BY user_id`?

Comment: Yes you're right. I've updated the query @bsarkar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved using [`Filter Aggregation`](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) and [`Terms Aggregation`](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).

```
{
   "aggs": {
      "users_owning_renault": {
         "filter": {
            "term": {
               "brand": "renault"
            }
         },
         "aggs": {
            "users": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "user_id",
                  "min_doc_count": 2,
                  "size": 0
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Taking the example documents you've mentioned, the response would be something like below:

```
{
   ...
   "aggregations": {
      "users_owning_renault": {
         "doc_count": 3,
         "users": {
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": 1,
                  "doc_count": 2
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here, `key` is `user_id` and `doc_count` is `matching`. When multiple users satisfy the search criteria, corresponding entires will be added to `buckets` array.

Comment: Nice. Is it possible to filter on a max_doc_count as well? To get results where matched is, say, between 2 and 4?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible using out of the box aggregation functionalities. But you can always take care of this filtering condition on the client side.